# SAP HANA - Activation warning: Could not found Naming Convention in table _SYS_BI.BIMC_CONFIGURATION for

Tags: warnings, hana

**When activating a procedure** I got the following warning:

Could not found Naming Convention in table _SYS_BI.BIMC_CONFIGURATION for ATTRIBUTEVIEW,ANALYTICVIEW,CALCULATIONVIEW,PROCEDURE,ANALYTIC PRIVILEGES,DECISION TABLE .

So I made the following inserts:

```
insert into _SYS_BI.BIMC_CONFIGURATION values ('NAMING_CONVENTION_RULE_ANALYTICVIEW', 'AN_');
insert into _SYS_BI.BIMC_CONFIGURATION values ('NAMING_CONVENTION_RULE_ATTRIBUTEVIEW', 'AT_');
insert into _SYS_BI.BIMC_CONFIGURATION values ('NAMING_CONVENTION_RULE_CALCULATIONVIEW', 'CA_');
insert into _SYS_BI.BIMC_CONFIGURATION values ('NAMING_CONVENTION_RULE_PROCEDURE', 'SP_');
insert into _SYS_BI.BIMC_CONFIGURATION values ('NAMING_CONVENTION_RULE_ANALYTIC_PRIVILEGES', 'AP_');
insert into _SYS_BI.BIMC_CONFIGURATION values ('NAMING_CONVENTION_RULE_DECISION_TABLE', 'DT_');
```

After that i still get a warning:

**Could not found Naming Convention in table _SYS_BI.BIMC_CONFIGURATION for  .**

Any ideas how to prevent the warning?

Answer (score 1):

This warning message gets printed erroneously and can safely be ignored.
To switch it off completely you can switch off the check for naming convention rule compliance altogether.
The setting for this can be found in

`Preferences 
    -> SAP HANA 
       -> Modeler 
          -> Validation Rules 
          -> Content 
          -> [ ] "Naming Convention Check"`

Generally this check is not used all that much anymore, as it only applies to activations done via SAP HANA Studio Modeler.
When objects are activated via the Web based editor, the checks are not performed.